# Publish angular 9+ library in npm with np

Tags: angular, npm

I trying to publish a library with `np` following the next steps:

1. `ng g workspace my-workspace`
2. `ng g library modal`
3. Code....
4. ng build modal --prod
5. Edit package.json inside `proyects/modal`

```js
{
  "name": "@myorg/modal",
  "version": "0.1.7",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.11",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.11"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "description": "Easy modal",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\"",
    "my-publish": "ng build modal --prod && np"
  },
  
 
  "license": "ISC",
 
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "np": {
    "contents": "./dist/modal"
  },

  //This try is new, but not working. 
  "module": "dist/modal/fesm2015/codice-progressio-modal.js",
  "es2015": "dist/modal/fesm2015/codice-progressio-modal.js",
  "esm2015": "dist/modal/esm2015/codice-progressio-modal.js",
  "fesm2015": "dist/modal/fesm2015/codice-progressio-modal.js",
  "typings": "dist/modal/codice-progressio-modal.d.ts",
  "metadata": "dist/modal/codice-progressio-modal.metadata.json",
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

6. Run my own npm script `npm run my-publish`
7. Install with `npm i @myorg/modal"`

After install, when I try to import ModalModule everythings crash. Thats because de library its not well published.

What I doing wrong? What I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem, I needed to copy `dist/` to my projects folder (modal). This is because npm cant up in path to the root workspace dir. After that, I use a preversion hook from npm to keep versioning from np.

I hope this will by helpfull for any one else.